# Copy folders in /data/data to sdcard & vice-versa

Tags: android, copy, root, android-sdcard, directory

I have a problem when I try to copy folders inside /data/data to SDcard.

I have my phone rooted.

I request Superuser permissions in my app with:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

I'm using `FileUtils` from Apache to copy files/folders.

What I discovered is if I manually change the folders permissions to `READ` I can copy it from /data/data to SDcard.

Is there any way to recursively change the `RW` permissions of all folders inside */data/data* to read and write folders?

I've tried `chmod` but It doesn't work.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 /data/data");
```

I want to do a backup program and i want to read some folders inside */data/data* and write them in a SDcard's folder.

Then I want to restore this folders reading them from a SDcard's folder and write them in */data/data*.

Could you help me, please?

Comment: It can be done because there is a program (Titanium Backup) which do that (It reads the files in /data/data/folder and copy in sdcard, and restore it)... Please, help me.

Comment: Is there any way to copy files and folders as superuser???

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the end I got it!!!!

I use the SuperUser process with the cp command to copy the files and folders.

I hope you find it helpful.

```
String comando = "cp -r /data/data/sourcefolder /sdcard/targetfolder";
Process suProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(suProcess.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes(comando + "\n");
os.flush();
os.writeBytes("exit\n");
os.flush();
try
{
 int suProcessRetval = suProcess.waitFor();
 if (255 != suProcessRetval)
 {
  // Acceso Root concedido
  retval = true;
 }else
 {
  // Acceso Root denegado
  retval = false;
 }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
 Log.w("Error ejecutando el comando Root", ex);
}
```

Thank you very much to all the people of this forum and for all the help which you offer!!