# How to copy /data/data files to /sdcard?

Tags: android, linux, shell

My APP need root privileges to do some analysis , so I write in my code as

" `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");` " ,then write linux command or shell script into it.

I tried to copy /data/data/packagename/databases/webview.db files to /sdcard/test (**the source database files is all the app data files exists in my cellphone , though java code I can only get the file of my app itself** ),

and then do some analysis.But the trouble is ,the source files name are the same, if I use

“`cp -r /data/data/*/webview.db  /sdcard/test`"

there is always only one file in the target directory,I was not so good at linux shell

command, so I want to know how to copy to the target directory and change the filename or just

keep the source directory structure like /sdcard/test/package/webview.db . I'm Chinese and my

English is not so well, hope you can understand it ,Thank you !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735273/copy-folders-in-data-data-to-sdcard-viceversa

Answer (score 2):

i am using this code and it's working great!

```
    public void copyDbToSdcard() {
        try {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

            if (sd.canWrite()) {
                String currentDBPath = "//data//" + this.getPackageName()
                        + "//databases//db";
                String backupDBPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .toString() + "/Darama1/db";
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

                if (currentDB.exists()) {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB)
                            .getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB)
                            .getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: But this can only get the database files of my APP itself, which I need is to get all the database files named webview.db in my cellphone.I think it need root privileges in linux command instead of just in java code.

Comment: i am trying to use your code but it says Multiple markers at this line
 - Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException
 - Resource leak: '<unassigned Closeable value>' is 
  never closed...... 
at new FileInputStream(currentDB)

Answer (score 0):

You can use adb.

Once you USB connect your device

you run:

adb -s YOURDEVICE pull /data/data/packagename/databases/webview.db

to know what your device is

you run:

adb devices

Doing so you have your webview.db file on your desktop and you can use it as you like

Comment: But I want to use linux command in my Android APP , I means my APP need root privileges to do the above thing ,so I write in my code as " Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su"); " ,then write linux command or shell script into it.Maybe I did't make a specific describe , sorry for that.