# unzipping files in /data/data/ folder - Android Java Programming

Tags: java, android, file, compression

How would I programmatically unzip backed up data directly into a `/data/data/com.appname` folder from the SD Card?

I am able to directly unzip folders in the `/data/data/com.appname` folder using ES File Explorer, however I need to automate this via the app I'm developing.

I've tried the following code, Unfortunately I am only able to unzip to the SD Card and data folder of my app.
I'm guessing this is due to some form of app/folder security?

**MainActivity.java**

```
package fb.ziptester;

import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void buttonOnClick(View v) {
    TextView zipSource = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.zip_source);
    TextView zipDest   = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.zip_dest);

    String sZipSource = "/storage/sdcard1/ACC/BU.zip";
    String sZipDest =   "/data/data/com.appname/";

    zipSource.setText(sZipSource);
    zipDest.setText(sZipDest);

    UnzipUtility zipUtil = new UnzipUtility();

    try {
        zipUtil.unzip(sZipSource, sZipDest);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
      //TODO
    }
  }
}  




package fb.ziptester;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;
```

**UnzipUtility.java**

```
public class UnzipUtility {
/**
 * Size of the buffer to read/write data
 */
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
/**
 * Extracts a zip file specified by the zipFilePath to a directory specified by
 * destDirectory (will be created if does not exists)
 * @param zipFilePath
 * @param destDirectory
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void unzip(String zipFilePath, String destDirectory) throws IOException {
    File destDir = new File(destDirectory);
    if (!destDir.exists()) {
        destDir.mkdir();
    }
    ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFilePath));
    ZipEntry entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
    // iterates over entries in the zip file
    while (entry != null) {
        String filePath = destDirectory + File.separator + entry.getName();
        if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
            // if the entry is a file, extracts it
            extractFile(zipIn, filePath);
        } else {
            // if the entry is a directory, make the directory
            File dir = new File(filePath);
            dir.mkdir();
        }
        zipIn.closeEntry();
        entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
    }
    zipIn.close();
}
/**
 * Extracts a zip entry (file entry)
 * @param zipIn
 * @param filePath
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void extractFile(ZipInputStream zipIn, String filePath) throws IOException {
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
    byte[] bytesIn = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int read = 0;
    while ((read = zipIn.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
        bos.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
    }
    bos.close();
 }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: It would appear that you are trying to hack the data of another app (`com.appname`) from your app (`fb.ziptester`). Fortunately, that is not possible, except on rooted devices.

Comment: My phone is rooted, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735273/copy-folders-in-data-data-to-sdcard-vice-versa perhaps this principle could be applied to extracting?

Comment: Off the cuff, your choices are either to unZIP in Java and then run a `su` command to move the results into the target directory, or figure out if you can run `unzIp` or the equivalent via `su`. I don't root, so I don't have practical recommendations here, other than to bear in mind that command-line binaries are not guaranteed to ship the same across devices.

Comment: Thank you for you input CommonsWare, In the end I decided to create an ext4 partition on my SD Card and store the data uncompressed. I've then used information regarding su commands from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735273/copy-folders-in-data-data-to-sdcard-vice-versa to copy the data directly into the /data/data/com.appname folder.